# OrientDB ETL does not import CSV

Tags: csv, import, etl, orientdb

I am a very new user of OrientDB and am evaluating it for use by my team.  I am unable to import my CSV file.  The CSV is a very simple file, as follows:

```
fld1,fld2,fld3
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

The JSON configuration file contains the following:

```
{
  "config": {
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "begin": [],
  "source": { "file": { "path": "../databases/metjsd.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {} },
  "transformers": [
    {
      "vertex": { "class": "metjsd" },
      "log" : {}
    }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/demodb",
       "dbAutoCreateProperties": true,
       "dbUser": "Admin",
       "dbPassword": "Admin",
       "classes": [
         {"name": "metjsd", "extends": "V"}
       ]
     }
  },
  "end": []
  }
```

The script I run in the command window is:

```
oetl metjsd.json
```

This is Community Edition 3.0.7 on Windows.  The command above is the oetl.bat file.

Some things I've tried:

- Stripping out all individual elements in the JSON configuration file that I think are non-essential, to the point that it looks like this:

  {
    "source": { "file": { "path": "../databases/metjsd.csv" } },
    "extractor": { "csv": {} },
    "transformers": [
      {
        "vertex": { "class": "metjsd" },
      }
    ],
    "loader": {
      "orientdb": {
         "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/demodb",
         "classes": [
           {"name": "metjsd", "extends": "V"}
         ]
       }
    }
- When I change the dbURL to another name, a new database is created, so I know that the JSON script is being read.
- When I change the source file path to a file that doesn't exist, an error is returned indicating a missing file, also indicating that the JSON file is being read.
- It doesn't make a difference whether I create the destination vertex class - no data is imported.
- Adding a debug to the JSON configuration file doesn't show debug information.

The result is the same each time - a single line showing the ETL version number, but nothing else.  No debug info.  No log output.  Just this:

```
C:\Users\John\Downloads\orientdb-3.0.7\orientdb-3.0.7\bin>oetl metjsd.json
OrientDB etl v.3.0.7 - Veloce (build eba5b2a2d63bf1b013db11db277226fcc4b9a34c, branch 3.0.x) https://www.orientdb.com
```

I've tried this on two Windows machines with the same results.

Everything I can see as a very novice user indicates that the OrientDB service and the database are OK.  Basic operations in OrientDB Studio are working as expeected.

Can anyone see something wrong with or missing from the JSON configuration file?  What else can I check?

*Appended Sept-13-2018*

Following are the revised CSV file and config file I'm using per the request below:

```
"fld1","fld2","fld3"
"a","b","c"
"d","e","f"
"g","h","i"


{
"config":{
  "log":"debug"
  },
  "begin": [],
  "source": { "file": { "path": "C:\Users\john.demar\Downloads\orientdb-3.0.7\orientdb-3.0.7\databases\metjsd.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {} },
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
        "dbURL": "remote:localhost/john",
        "serverUser":"root",
        "serverPassword":"orientdb",
        "dbType":"document",
        "dbAutoCreateProperties":true,
        "classes": [
          {"name": "metjsd"}
         ]
     }
  },
  "end": []
}
```

Comment: my suggestion is to use absolute path. Moreover, you can't use a plocal database (embedded) when the server is running. Stop the server or change the configuration from plocal: to remote:localhost/<yourdb>

Comment: Thanks.  I made those changes and now get this error:

    Suppressed: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSecurityAccessException: Wrong user/password to [connect] to the remote OrientDB Server instance.

This is true whether I set dbUser/dbPassword to admin/admin, exclude those from the config file, or use a non-default admin user that I've set up.

Comment: Follow-up - All of the users I've tried can authenticate in OrientDB Studio with no problem and can make successful API calls using Postman.

Comment: I see in your config file Admin with the first capital letter, use "admin", all lowercase.

Comment: Thanks.  Since posting this, I have tried all the users in lower case username 
+ password.  I have since added dbServerUser and dbServerPassword and got a little farther - the vertex was added, but none of the properties implicit in the CSV file column names.  Also, there was not more feedback in the console.  So, the data is still not importing.  In addition to that problem, I'm wondering why I had to as the server user+password.  None of the online examples indicated this need.

Comment: you need serverAdmin and password if you want the ETL to create the database. Can you re-post your updated conf with a sample file?

Comment: You are right about needing serveruser and serverpassword to create the database.  The database already exists, but the ETL won't create the class without those server user credentials.  The docs don't indicate this need, and I can't imagine why server user credentials are needed for creating a new class.  Please see above for the most recent conf file and CSV I'm using.  I've also tried importing from SQL Server and having the same issue, so this doesn't seem limited to CSV imports, but I want to solve the CSV issues first then apply the adjustments to my SQL import attempt.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a missing "class" parameter in the Loader section.  A Transformer is not needed, which fits my scenario because I don't know the properties that might come in.

The documentation doesn't indicate that the "class" property is required.  All the examples I found used the "classes" property, and using that alone seemed to be appropriate because the class was created, just no properties and no file import.  Adding the "class" property created the class with all its properties.

This config file finally worked:

```
{
"config":{
  "log":"debug"
  },
  "begin": [],
  "source": { "file": { "path": "C:\jsd\orientdb-3.0.7\databases\metjsd.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {}},
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
        "dbURL": "remote:localhost/john",
        "serverUser":"root",
        "serverPassword":"orientdb",
        "dbType":"document",
        "dbAutoCreateProperties":true,
        "class": "metjsd"
     }
  },
  "end": []
}
```

Comment: I lost many time to find out etl module work with serverUser not dbUser

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works for me.
Loads each row as a Vertex of class metjsd.
You didn't provide a transformer in your configuration.

```
{
"config":{
  "log":"debug"
  },
  "begin": [],
  "source": { "file": { "path": "C:\Users\john.demar\Downloads\orientdb-3.0.7\orientdb-3.0.7\databases\metjsd.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {} },
  "transformers": [
   {
     "vertex": { "class": "metjsd" },
     "log" : {}
   }
 ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
        "dbURL": "remote:localhost/john",
        "dbUser": "admin",
       "dbPassword": "admin",
        "serverUser":"root",
        "serverPassword":"orientdb",
        "dbType":"graph",
        "dbAutoCreateProperties":true,
        "classes": [
          {"name": "metjsd"}
         ]
     }
  },
  "end": []
}
```

Here's the output on OrientDB Studio

[image]

Comment: It tried with and without a transformer.  The docs don't indicate that one is necessary or that even a placeholder entry for a transformer is needed.  For my testing purposes, the data does not need to be transformed.  Are you saying that all you did was add a transformer entry and it worked?

Comment: The reason I did not add a transformer is because there will be cases where we don't know the structure of the incoming data, so we want to import it "as-is" with no modifications, hence no transformations.  For that matter, we would not want anything specific in the Extractor section, either, other than indicating that the source is a CSV file.

Comment: The transformer does nothing more than assigning a class to the incoming data. As you can see, I added the transformer AND the username and password of the database other than server credentials. The JSON Is exactly what I used locally.  Note that there's a record (28:0) because I have an empty line in my csv: my fault